# When does hdfs change Access time and modification time of a directory?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Suppose I have a the following hierarchy in my hdfs file system

```
Dir1
  -> Dir2
     -> File1
```

If I add a file named File 2 to /Dir1/Dir2, are the access and modification time of Dir1 and Dir2 going to change ? In general, when do these two values change ?

Also How to access those two values through the Hadoop Java API ?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

The time stamp of `Dir2` changes but not for `Dir1`. Only the immediate directory timestamp changes.

You can use the following in Java for getting timestamp :

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
long moddificationTime = fs
    .getFileStatus((FileSplit)context.getInputSplit())
    .getPath()).lastModified();
```

Comment: I can't find the function lastModified in the Java API, which version of the API are you using ? Also, any reason why Hadoop does not change the timestamp of all parent directories ?